# Is there an automated way to update the SSH name when starting or restarting a Google/AWS cloud instance with the public IP address of that instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-ec2, ssh, gcloud

I often have a set of spot instances in stopped state at Google Cloud or Amazon AWS for various specific reasons.

When I start those instances I typically look up its public IP address and then update my `.ssh/config` entry with that public IP. Then use it normally.

This works fine but when things get busier, I need to update frequently and that takes time.

What I do for more frequent used instances (one or two) is to update the DNS entry programatically by running a bash script regularly. It looks something like this:

This works fine for continuously running instances but it is sort of unreliable and it might also miss half an hour - you do not want to run the above every minute for many machines.

What I am really looking is a client-side solution that updates my `.ssh/config` or perhaps local DNS (/etc/hosts?) instead of relying on going to Route53 and changing DNS, which can get messy.

I was going to write a script to do this semi-automated update (can still be hand triggered) using the Google/AWS command line tools but thought about asking if there is an open source or standard tool to do this.

The solution would be used on Linux/Ubuntu clients and servers

Thank you!

Comment: The bash script is not inserted.

Comment: That bash script is server-side. It relies on fetching the public IP with `curl ifconfig.me` which of course does not work on client-side. It would be useless here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my little CLI command that you can repurpose to get the list of the public IP addresses of your AWS EC2 instances:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Instance:InstanceId,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,PublicIP:PublicIpAddress,State:State.Name,Subnet:SubnetId,AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone}"
```

Comment: Thanks! It's the part that updates the "system" (ssh/config or /etc/hosts) that is missing here. Perhaps I wanted to tag the instance, retrieve that tag and update ssh/config with that name. That would be awesome

Comment: There is a related solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402780/preferable-way-to-automatically-update-ssh-config-file-using-python/75561547#75561547   If you want to update yours with that, I will give you the question.